# How can I run a third party fat JAR in Amazon Lambda?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jar, aws-lambda

Suppose I have a third party jar called tp.jar

When running ordinarily from the command line, I would run:

```
java -cp tp.jar com.tp.Start
```

I've tried to run this in Amazon Lambda by using Runtime:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("java -cp tp.jar com.tp.Start");
```

inside my handleRequest method

Aside from seeming hacky, I can't seem to get this method to work. I'm not sure if Amazon Lambda place any restrictions on the use of Runtime.getRuntime()

Is there any way of simply running:

```
java -cp tp.jar com.tp.Start
```

on AWS Lambda?